# How to convert Node.js to python

Tags: python, node.js, api, get

Hello everyone i want to convert this snippet of node.js code to python  and i am not too particularly strong in python. For a little backstory I am performing a api get request to pull data, I specifically want to pull everything(fields and value ) that is in one table. so far from the node.js snippet I understand that I am reading a txt file using a for loop to iterate through all the fields that is in one table in an index but I do not know how to implement this in my python code. Any recommendations that may help?

here is a tables.txt file

```
{"Tables":
    [
        {
            "Name": "Event",
            "EventType": "CSummary",
            "Fields": "*",
            "SortBy": "WhenOccurred",
            "SortType": "Date",
            "Last": "01/14/2020 16:02:00 -05:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have done so far but i dont know how to progress forward

```
scriptfile = open('tables.txt','r+')
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json={"script": " this is a work in progress"}, verify=verify)
resources = json.dumps(scriptfile)
for table in range(len(resources):
```

Here is the node.js snippet that I want to convert.

```
function GetSecrets(authToken, authCookie, next) {

            let resources = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('tables.txt').toString());

            console.log("Tables to get: " + resources.Tables.length);

            // Loop through all the tables to get
            for (let i = 0; i < resources.Tables.length; i++) {
                let thisResource = resources.Tables[i];
                let tableName = thisResource.Name;
                let sortBy = thisResource.SortBy;
                let lastGot = thisResource.Last;
                let fields = thisResource.Fields;
                let sortType = thisResource.SortType;
                let eventType = thisResource.EventType;
                let fileName = '';

                let sql = '';

                if (tableName === 'Event') {
                    sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Event.EventType IN ('" + eventType + "') AND " + tableName + "." + sortBy + " > DateFunc('" + lastGot + "') ORDER BY " + tableName + "." + sortBy + ";"

                    fileName = "Event-" + eventType;
                } else {
                    if (sortType === 'None') {
                        sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + ";";
                    } else {
                        sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "." + sortBy + " > DateFunc('" + lastGot + "') ORDER BY " + tableName + "." + sortBy + ";"
                    }
                    fileName = tableName;
                }


            post_data = JSON.stringify({
                "Script": sql,
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

this shuld work for you:

```
import json
def GetSecrets(resources):
    resources = json.load(open("tables.txt"))
    print(f"Tables to get: {len(resources)}")
    for resource in resources.values():    
        tableName = resource[0]["Name"]
        sortBy = resource[0]["SortBy"]
        lastGot = resource[0]["Last"]
        fields = resource[0]["Fields"]
        sortType = resource[0]["SortType"]
        eventType = resource[0]["EventType"]        
        if tableName == "Event":
            sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Event.EventType IN ('" + eventType + "') AND " + tableName + "." + sortBy + " > DateFunc('" + lastGot + "') ORDER BY " + tableName + "." + sortBy + ""
            fileName = "Event-" + eventType
        elif sortType=="None":
            sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + ""
        else:
            sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "." + sortBy + " > DateFunc('" + lastGot + "') ORDER BY " + tableName + "." + sortBy + ""
            fileName = tableName
    return f"Script: {sql}"
```

Comment: This only print how many tables that are in the textfile  I dont  print out  the sql response

Comment: Nevermind I am able to get it working  but I have another question I am going to add more events and this approach is going through one occurrence ([0]) how do i go through each occurrence?

Comment: Try changing resources.items to resources["Tables"] and just remove The [0]

Comment: And change The return to print if you just want to print the queries

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't fit on Stack Overflow. You don't have a specific problem with your code.

You can learn [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) how to iterate over an array in Python.

If your `resources` is a "complex" object, then you probably want to read about [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Comment: I apologize I should have been more accurate how can I iterate thorough all the tables in python?

Comment: There are multiple ways you can do it. I will update my answer with some links. Please, update you question with explicit details of what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether such questions are acceptable here or not.

I hope this can help you.

```py
import json

with open('tables.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data['Tables']:
        tableName = p['Name']
        sortBy = p['SortBy']
        lastGot = p['Last']
        fields = p['Fields']
        sortType = p['SortType']
        eventType = p['EventType']
        fileName = ""
        sql = ""

        if (tableName == 'Event'):
            sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Event.EventType IN ('" + eventType + "') AND " + tableName + "." + sortBy + " > DateFunc('" + lastGot + "') ORDER BY " + tableName + "." + sortBy + ";"

            fileName = "Event-" + eventType
        else:
            if (sortType == 'None'):
                sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + ";";
            else:
                sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + "." + sortBy + " > DateFunc('" + lastGot + "') ORDER BY " + tableName + "." + sortBy + ";"

            fileName = tableName

print(sql)
```

Comment: thank you for your response I got an error saying ```Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 37, in <module>
    lastGot = p['Last']
KeyError: 'Last'
```

Comment: @Xfactor check if this key exists in text file.

Comment: it does exist in the file which mind boggling to me

Comment: could you share some part of it in pastebin ? https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I am testing the code [here](https://repl.it/@meherremoff/Node-js-to-python), it seems to work fine. You can also check it by adding more data to the text file.